# Почему сообщения, отправляемые в rsyslog, пишутся ещё и в /var/log/message и как от этого избавиться?

Tags: python, логирование, rsyslog

Задался целью писать логи в **свой** логфайл, но в /var/log/

Для того, чтобы это провернуть нужен rsyslog/syslog

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
import logging.handlers

def main():
    log_instance = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    log_instance.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    fhandle = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/dev/log', facility='local5')
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

    fhandle.setFormatter(formatter)

    log_instance.addHandler(fhandle)
    log_instance.info('New information String')    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

В файл rsyslog.conf добавил:

```
local5.*                                      /var/log/status.log
```

service rsyslog restart

На удивление работает!

Вопросы:

1. До конца непонятно всеже что такое facility?
2. Почему переменных local согласно [документации](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html) от 0 до 7?
3. Как же все-таки прекратить писать в messages по мимо своего лога?
4. откуда берется первая дата в строке лога `Jul 27 09:50:25 Server` ведь я её не указывал.

Jul 27 15:50:25 Server 2018-07-27 15:50:25,447 **main** INFO New information String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Относитесь к `facility` как группе/типу/классу сообщений. Например, в системе есть два сервиса: `postfix` и `dovecot`. Они генерируют сообщения с facility равным `mail`. Следовательно все сообщения от них можно "сгруппировать" в файл /var/log/maillog.
2. Фасилити (типов) `local` восемь штук согласно [другой](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424) документации. Почему их 8 - не знаю. Вероятно (исторически и технически) предполагается, что этого вполне достаточно для одной системы с сислогом.
3. Чтобы прекратить писать в `messages` нужно в конфиге rsyslog найти строчку, которая описывает все типы сообщений для записи в /var/log/messages.

Например может выглядеть так:

```
*.info;authpriv.none;cron.none    /var/log/messages
```

Добавьте к этой строке `local5.none`:

```
*.info;authpriv.none;cron.none;local5.none    /var/log/messages
```

Чтобы исключить попадание логов с фасилити local5 в messages.

4. Syslog самостоятельно добавляет TIMESTAMP к сообщению. Скорее всего в конфиге вашего rsyslog есть строка: `$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat`. Закомментируйте ее. Получится формат времени на подобии такого: `2018-07-30T09:29:06.924146+03:00`. Соответственно, в коде можно будет убрать `%(asctime)s`.